# Selenium VBA select option input element

Tags: vba, selenium

I'm using Excel VBA, Selenium and Chrome.

Threse is a dropdownbox box and I'm trying to select an option. Html code is:

```
<div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-abs-layout-item x-trigger-wrap-focus" id="ext-gen437" style="width: 100px; left: 330px; top: 70px;">

<input maxlength="1" spellcheck="false" id="ext-comp-1233" name="CITTADINANZA"        class="x-form-text x-form-field x-field-uppercase x-trigger-noedit x-form-focus" readonly="" style="width: 75px;" />

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" id="ext-gen438" />

</div>
```

The dispalyed text options are "Si" and "No" but in Html code there are no options, index, value...(it's just an input element; the img element is the arrow you have to click for a dropdown)

I tried to fill the input element using:

```
driver.FindElementByCss("#ext-comp-1233").AsSelect.SelectByIndex
driver.FindElementByCss("#ext-comp-1233").AsSelect.SelectByValue
driver.FindElementByCss("#ext-comp-1233").AsSelect.SelectByText
driver.FindElementByCss("#ext-comp-1233").Sendkeys
```

but I recive the error:
"Unexpected TagName Error.
Expected=select
Got=input"

...while Sendkeys doesn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: It seems that the dropdown element is dynamic. So it may not be a select element. You can try clicking on the down arrow image, wait for a second, and click on the drop down entry. You may first inspect the drop down after clicking on the image to see the real html code

Comment: @ShalvinAbraham Thank you for answer. After clicking on the image the input html code doesn't change, only change a bit the class code of div. I can click on the down arrow image and sendkey a downarrow but when I sendkey enter (for choose the option) is not working.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the option element ? I think it will be another div.

Comment: @ShalvinAbraham What/where is the option element? I can't find other hmtl elements than I posted (

Comment: These dynamic elements work in such a way that, JavaScript is used to dynamically create elements. What you can try is, click on the dropdown (down arrow image) and once you see the options, right click on one of them and choose inspect element. Then, you will see more elements inside the input element, or other element. Can you check this out?

Comment: @ShalvinAbraham You are right! The right click is disabled but I found the generated element and it is a div: <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen493" style="width: 98px; height: 46px;"><div class="x-combo-list-item"></div><div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Si</div><div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">No</div></div>. Now I'm trying to select an options using this div but I recive the expecion that it's not visible..

Comment: Cool... Now, you can click on element with xpath as //div[text()="myoption"]

Comment: One more hint. In chrome, you will not be able to click on invisible objects. You will get errors that click will hit another object. Do a trick. Try element.SendKeys(Keys. space)

Comment: @ShalvinAbraham Ok, it's solved. When I click on the img that dropdown the box the div become visible and it's possibile to click and choose an option. Thank you very much for your precious help!!! Have a nice evening ;)

Comment: I have summarized the solution as answer to this question. Please mark it as answer since the issue is resolved. Have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

`obj.FindElementByXPath("xpath of element").AsSelect.SelectByText ("option text")`

Note:
driver - name of the object you've created for webdriver.

Comment: This was enough to help me figure out what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to click on the drop down image, and when the dynamically created divs are displayed, click on those divs.