# Selecting an option value within a frame

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

OK. I've been playing with this for way too long now. I am doing a web-scrape using the chrome-driver for Selenium and VBA. I am able to paste elements from my Excel file onto the page (includes switching frames), switching to a next window, getting results and back to original webpage and moving to next row in Excel, etc. My problem is I have yet to be able to discover the proper method to select an item in a drop-down box. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide code and HTML and possibly an URL. It is easy usually but we need some context.

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32904670/4650297) help? Or any of [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+vba+drop+down+list)? It seems there are a lot of questions similar to yours online ...What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you. Please bear with me as I retest. The link provided by BruceWayne appears promising. I will provide some HTML if this does not work.

Comment: BruceWayne.. Not sure how I missed this one (maybe can't form a good question) but that indeed was the answer. Many thanks.